# How to pass an array to postgres function and loop before updating

Tags: php, arrays, json, postgresql, codeigniter

I have a scenario where I want to pass an array or json data of primary keys to the postgres function and then loop through that json or array data before i update each record.
I have searched for two days now but cant get the codes that works,help please.
Here is my sample function and its parameters

```
$this->db->query(
  "select create_booking_bn_annual_maintenance($business_id,  $this->client_id, $unpaid_years, $bn_maintenance_ids)");
```

I am using codeigniter framework to call the function and pass the values

Very grateful for your help

Comment: And here is what is being passed   create_booking_bn_annual_maintenance(18438, 61171, 3, ["73","74","75"])

Comment: What is the purpose of doing the loop before update? What will the loop do for you?

Comment: each element in an array is a primary key,therefore i want to update the table by setting a status for each element in the array and thus i do it with a loop

Comment: You need to show the code for your function - where the update is actually occurring. It sounds like you may not need to loop at all. You should be able to simply reference the array directly in the `WHERE` clause in PostgreSQL. Something like `WHERE id_col = ANY(bn_maintenance_ids);`

Comment: Here is the part of the code CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_booking_bn_annual_maintenance(
id bigint,
client_id bigint,
yr bigint,
maintenance_ids INT[])
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
update bn_maintenance set booking_id = (select booking_id from booking where invoice = randChar) where bn_maintenance_ids IN(maintenance_ids)  and business_id=id;